# Laravel 5.6 model extends other model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my package I have come model with it own namespace

```
<?php

namespace Nosennij\LaravelCategoryMenuAndBreadcrumbs\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function scopeMain($query)
    {
        return $query->where('parent_id', 0);
    }

    public function subcategories(){
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

When I install package it will be good if I do not copy this model to app folder and do not change namespace to App. It will be better to extend this model from package imporing all parent methods. I try to do it next way
1) `php artisan make:model Category`
2) try to extend

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Nosennij\LaravelCategoryMenuAndBreadcrumbs\models\Category as ParentCategory;

class Category extends ParentCategory
{
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        parent::boot();
    }
    //my own new methods or methods rewriting parent methods
}
```

How can I do it?

[image]

So in controller I want to `use App\Category;` and want to have acces to `scopeMain`, `subcategories`, `parent` methods from package model in `vendor/nosennij/laravel-catmenubread/models/Category.php`

Working variant- https://github.com/n-osennij/laravel-category

Comment: I think you better create your own artisan command for that

Comment: Is there anything the matter with using the second option? Are you getting an error? Is the `Nosennij\LaravelCategoryMenuAndBreadcrumbs\models\Category` class extend the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class itself?

Comment: @RossWilson first code example - it is first general model in my package. Second code example - model in App folder. And I try to add all mthods from first model to second. I get an error - `Class 'Nosennij\LaravelCategoryMenuAndBreadcrumbs\models\Category' not found`, but if I click to this class in phpstorm i can see it. And answer on second question - yes, look at first code example.

Comment: Are you installing it with composer and then copying from vendor to app, or are you copying it from somewhere else?

Comment: @RossWilson It is my own package. I try to learn how to make it - https://github.com/n-osennij/laravel-catmenubread . I install `composer require nosennij/laravel-catmenubread` and `php artisan vendor:publish --force` and try now create my own Category model (second code example in this questios) which will extends package model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your package move your `models` directory under `src` and capitalize the `M` e.g. `src/Models/Category.php`.

Then change the namespace in `Category` to be:

```
namespace Nosennij\LaravelCategoryMenuAndBreadcrumbs\Models;
```

Then in your `Category` class in your app directory change it to be:

```
use Nosennij\LaravelCategoryMenuAndBreadcrumbs\Models\Category as ParentCategory;

class Category extends ParentCategory
```

Comment: I want my `app/Category.php` exends `vendor/nosennij/laravel-catmenubread/models/Category.php` - not `vendor/nosennij/laravel-catmenubread/src/LaravelCategoryMenuAndBreadcrumbs.php` like you say. Why my class `vendor/nosennij/laravel-catmenubread/src/LaravelCategoryMenuAndBreadcrumbs.php` need to extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. `Eloquent\Model` - it is only for models. My models in `vendor/nosennij/laravel-catmenubread/models` patch.

Comment: Yo answer help my to find soltion. I have error in my namespaces. So I mode `model` folder to `src` and add some other fixes. Now I can easy extend model `use Nosennij\LaravelCategoryMenuAndBreadcrumbs\models\Category as ParentCategory;`

Comment: Oh sorry, I was looking in your `src` directory because that's where you'd set your PSR autoload to be...my bad.